# objectmaker.exe in haarclassification

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am trying  in vs2012 and opencv 2.4.11 to run the objectmaker.exe in my project file which is created by the code and successfully build in release but when i am trying to double click to open it there is a run time error i cant fix it  any help please .. my code is :

```
  #include <opencv/cv.h>
  #include <opencv/cvaux.h>
  #include <opencv/highgui.h>
  #include "stdafx.h"

  #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
  // for filelisting
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <io.h>
  // for fileoutput
  #include <string>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <sstream>
  #include "dirent.h"
  #include <sys/types.h>

  using namespace std;
  using namespace cv;

  IplImage* image=0;
  IplImage* image2=0;
  //int start_roi=0;
  int roi_x0=0;
  int roi_y0=0;
  int roi_x1=0;
  int roi_y1=0;
  int numOfRec=0;
  int startDraw = 0;
  char* window_name="<SPACE>add <ENTER>save and load next <ESC>exit";

  string IntToString(int num)
  {
      ostringstream myStream; //creates an ostringstream object
      myStream << num << flush;
    /*
* outputs the number into the string stream and then flushes
* the buffer (makes sure the output is put into the stream)
*/
return(myStream.str()); //returns the string form of the stringstream object
  };

  void on_mouse(int event,int x,int y,int flag, void *param)
  {
if(event==CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
{
    if(!startDraw)
    {
        roi_x0=x;
        roi_y0=y;
        startDraw = 1;
    } else {
        roi_x1=x;
        roi_y1=y;
        startDraw = 0;
    }
}
if(event==CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && startDraw)
{

    //redraw ROI selection
    image2=cvCloneImage(image);
                     cvRectangle(image2,cvPoint(roi_x0,roi_y0),cvPoint(x,y),
   CV_RGB(255,0,255),1);
    cvShowImage(window_name,image2);
    cvReleaseImage(&image2);
}

  }

  int main(int argc, char** argv)
  {
    int iKey=0;
      string strPrefix;
       string strPostfix;
    string input_directory;
    string output_file;

    if(argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s output_info.txt raw/data/directory/\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
    } 

    input_directory = argv[2];
      output_file = argv[1];

    /* Get a file listing of all files with in the input directory */
    DIR *dir_p = opendir (input_directory.c_str());
    struct dirent *dir_entry_p;

if(dir_p == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open directory %s\n",                   input_directory.c_str());
    return -1;
}

fprintf(stderr, "Object Marker: Input Directory: %s  Output File: %s\n", input_directory.c_str(), output_file.c_str());

//  init highgui
cvAddSearchPath(input_directory);
cvNamedWindow(window_name,1);
cvSetMouseCallback(window_name,on_mouse, NULL);

fprintf(stderr, "Opening directory...");
//  init output of rectangles to the info file
ofstream output(output_file.c_str());
fprintf(stderr, "done.\n");

while((dir_entry_p = readdir(dir_p)) != NULL)
{
    numOfRec=0;

    if(strcmp(dir_entry_p->d_name, ""))
    fprintf(stderr, "Examining file %s\n", dir_entry_p->d_name);

    /* TODO: Assign postfix/prefix info */
    strPostfix="";
    strPrefix=input_directory;
    strPrefix+=dir_entry_p->d_name;
    //strPrefix+=bmp_file.name;
    fprintf(stderr, "Loading image %s\n", strPrefix.c_str());

    if((image=cvLoadImage(strPrefix.c_str(),1)) != 0)
    {

        //  work on current image
        do
        {
            cvShowImage(window_name,image);

            // used cvWaitKey returns:
            //  <Enter>=13      save added rectangles and show next image
            //  <ESC>=27        exit program
            //  <Space>=32      add rectangle to current image
            //  any other key clears rectangle drawing only
            iKey=cvWaitKey(0);
            switch(iKey)
            {
            case 27:
                    cvReleaseImage(&image);
                    cvDestroyWindow(window_name);
                    return 0;
            case 32:
                    numOfRec++;
            printf("   %d. rect x=%d\ty=%d\tx2h=%d\ty2=%d\n",numOfRec,roi_x0,roi_y0,roi_x1,roi_y1);
            //printf("   %d. rect x=%d\ty=%d\twidth=%d\theight=%d\n",numOfRec,roi_x1,roi_y1,roi_x0-roi_x1,roi_y0-roi_y1);
                    // currently two draw directions possible:
                    //      from top left to bottom right or vice versa
                    if(roi_x0<roi_x1 && roi_y0<roi_y1)
                    {
                        printf("   %d. rect x=%d\ty=%d\twidth=%d\theight=%d\n",numOfRec,roi_x0,roi_y0,roi_x1-roi_x0,roi_y1-roi_y0);
                        // append rectangle coord to previous line content
                        strPostfix+=" "+IntToString(roi_x0)+" "+IntToString(roi_y0)+" "+IntToString(roi_x1-roi_x0)+" "+IntToString(roi_y1-roi_y0);
                    }
                    if(roi_x0>roi_x1 && roi_y0>roi_y1)
                    {
                        printf("   %d. rect x=%d\ty=%d\twidth=%d\theight=%d\n",numOfRec,roi_x1,roi_y1,roi_x0-roi_x1,roi_y0-roi_y1);
                        // append rectangle coord to previous line content
                        strPostfix+=" "+IntToString(roi_x1)+" "+IntToString(roi_y1)+" "+IntToString(roi_x0-roi_x1)+" "+IntToString(roi_y0-roi_y1);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        while(iKey!=13);

        // save to info file as later used for HaarTraining:
        //  <rel_path>\bmp_file.name numOfRec x0 y0 width0 height0 x1 y1 width1 height1...
        if(numOfRec>0 && iKey==13)
        {
            //append line
            /* TODO: Store output information. */
            output << strPrefix << " "<< numOfRec << strPostfix <<"\n";
        }

        cvReleaseImage(&image);

    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load image, %s\n", strPrefix.c_str());
    }
}


output.close();
cvDestroyWindow(window_name);
closedir(dir_p);


return 0;
```

}

Comment: please avoid any code with IplImage* in it. opencv's legacy c-api is no more acceptable.

Comment: please use opencv's [annotation tool](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4/apps/annotation) instead of your outdated code above.